# Tensorflow: is there a way to load a pretrained model without having to redefine all the variables?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to split my code into different modules, one where the model is trained, another which analyzes the weights in the model.

When I save the model using

```
save_path = saver.save(sess, "checkpoints5/text8.ckpt")
```

It makes 4 files, ['checkpoint', 'text8.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001', 'text8.ckpt.meta', 'text8.ckpt.index']

I tried restoring this in the separate module using this code

```
train_graph = tf.Graph()
with train_graph.as_default():
    saver = tf.train.Saver()


with tf.Session(graph=train_graph) as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('MODEL4'))
    embed_mat = sess.run(embedding)
```

But I get this error message

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-deaad9b67888> in <module>()
      1 train_graph = tf.Graph()
      2 with train_graph.as_default():
----> 3     saver = tf.train.Saver()
      4 
      5 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in __init__(self, var_list, reshape, sharded, max_to_keep, keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours, name, restore_sequentially, saver_def, builder, defer_build, allow_empty, write_version, pad_step_number, save_relative_paths, filename)
   1309           time.time() + self._keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours * 3600)
   1310     elif not defer_build:
-> 1311       self.build()
   1312     if self.saver_def:
   1313       self._check_saver_def()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in build(self)
   1318     if context.executing_eagerly():
   1319       raise RuntimeError("Use save/restore instead of build in eager mode.")
-> 1320     self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
   1321 
   1322   def _build_eager(self, checkpoint_path, build_save, build_restore):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in _build(self, checkpoint_path, build_save, build_restore)
   1343           return
   1344         else:
-> 1345           raise ValueError("No variables to save")
   1346       self._is_empty = False
   1347 

ValueError: No variables to save
```

After reading up on this issue, it seems that I need to redefine all the variables used when I trained the model.

Is there a way to access the weights without having to redefine everything? The weights are just numbers, surely there must be a way to access them directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just accessing variables in checkpoints, please checkout the [`checkpoint_utils`](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_utils.py) library. It provides three useful api function: `load_checkpoint`, `list_variables` and `load_variable`. I'm not sure if there is a better way but you can certainly use these functions to extract a dict of all variables in a checkpoint like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ckpt = 'checkpoints5/text8.ckpt'
var_dict = {name: tf.train.load_checkpoint(ckpt).get_tensor(name)
            for name, _ in tf.train.list_variables(ckpt)}
print(var_dict)
```

To load a pretrained model without having to redefine all the variables, you will need more than just checkpoints. A checkpoint has only variables and it doesn't how to restore these variables, i.e. how to map them to a graph, without an actual graph (and an appropriate map). [`SavedModel`](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#build_and_load_a_savedmodel) will be better for this scenario. It can save both the model [`MetaGraph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/meta_graph) and all variables. You don't have to manually redefine everything when restoring the saved model. The following code is an example using just the [`simple_save`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/simple_save).

To save a trained model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y_ = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1])
y_ = tf.layers.dense(y_, units=1)
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=x, predictions=y_)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for _ in range(10):
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x: range(10)})
    # Let's check the bias here so that we can make sure
    # the model we restored later on is indeed our trained model here.
    d_b = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('dense/bias:0')
    print(sess.run(d_b))
    tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, 'test', inputs={"x": x}, outputs={"y": y_})
```

To restore the saved model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    # A model saved by simple_save will be treated as a graph for inference / serving,
    # i.e. uses the tag tag_constants.SERVING
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], 'test')
    d_b = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('dense/bias:0')
    print(sess.run(d_b))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a question about line " d_b = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('dense/bias:0')". Shouldn't get_tensor_by_name input the name of the tensor, so y_ in this case? And what does '/bias:0' do ?

Comment: @patrick-j-fitzgerald This is specific to my made-up example, which uses `tf.layers.dense`. `y_` is the prediction which is indeed a tensor but is not a variable. And its name is not `"y_"` but `"dense/BiasAdd:0"`. It comes from the last op of the dense layer "dense/BiasAdd". For tensor name it is of the form "<op_name>:<output_index>".

Comment: @PatrickJFitzgerald There are two trainable variables in my example: `dense/kernel:0` and `dense/bias:0` which are built by `tf.layers.dense` and you can find them out through `tf.trainable_variables()`. Since your question was focusing on variables, I used `dense/bias:0` to show you the method provided in my answer indeed restored the value from the last training step.